# django-registration activates user but shows error

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm using django-registration which somehow stopped working the way it should work. I'm completely lost on this and have no idea where to start looking for the error.

So what happens is, that whenever a user clicks on the activation link, he gets the activation.html template. Which should only be shown when there was an error.

But actually there is no error. The user gets activated and can log in.

Any thoughts on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the subject of your post and the actual description are conflicting. The subject says django-registration always fails to activate the user, but then in your description you say the user gets activated and can log in. Which is it?

Secondly, clicking on the activation link should always send the user to activate.html. You will have a variable called `account` on that page. If the activation was successful, `account` will be populated with the User object, otherwise it will be False.

Comment: You are right, i fixed the title. But I think you are wrong with your answer. At least the documentation: http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/views.html says that "On unsuccessful activation, will render the template registration/activate.html to display an error message; to override thise, pass the argument template_name (see below)."

Comment: Indeed. In the docs: `registration/activate.html: Used if account activation fails.`

Comment: Ah, so you're using version 0.8 which apparently went through a complete rewrite. I'm still using an older version which is what I was basing my answer on. Sorry about that.

Comment: I was using 0.7 (latest Version in pypi) by accident. Now upgraded back to the latest version from bitbucket, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Beeing out of options, I just changed my template. Either the docs are wrong, or I messed something else up. Doesn't really matter because it is working now. :)

Comment: It's unfortunate that you weren't able to resolve this. I would suggest that you post about this issue on the project page on bitbucket. After all, you need a way to handle invalid activation links - sounds like you are not going to be doing that with this fix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between 0.7 and 0.8:

in 0.7:

**registration/activate.html** is displayed when a user attempts to
  activate his/her account.

in 0.8

**registration/activate.html**

Used if account activation fails.

Comment: oh and I can't find the nicely formatted online docs for 0.7, but 0.8 is only in alpha. hrmph.

Comment: docs for 0.7 https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/d073602dc103/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Debugging registration.views.activate showed: if the `success_url` isn't set, 
the `backend.post_activation_redirect` method is called. If you're using the default backend, that returns an empty context without the account variable which is queried in the template.
The solution could be to overwrite the default backend. 
The only problem is that you cannot pass any objects to views over a redirect. Hence, you cannot pass the account to the template context. You could do it with get params if wanted to.
I decided to just change the activation template and remove the condition.